# How can i replace string value in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have string value 'jai'

I want to replace this string as follow 'j_a_i'

How Can i Do that?

I have used Following SQL Query:

```
update photos set filename = replace(filename, ' ', '_');
```

But it Update Only Space in string.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Hint:  `replace(filename,  'jai ',  'j_a_i')`

Comment: try `update photos set filename = replace(filename, '', '_');` without the blank

Comment: In general you are going to need a regex replacement for that.  Which database are you using?

Comment: if you want to split the string by character like what it looks like what you want to do here, is either use a Regex to go through and do the replace, or use recursion to look at the string, create a sub string, get the last index, add 1 and then update your value.  ether that, or just do a proper update script with a setting a new name with a where clause.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a function and call this function in the `select` or `update` statement.
This is now in `MSSQL`, but you can do similiar in `MySQL` or something else

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION Split_String(@string nvarchar(255))
RETURNS nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @counter int = 1
    declare @returnString nvarchar(max) = ''
    while (@counter <= len(@string))
    begin
        set @returnString = @returnString + SUBSTRING ( @string ,@counter , 1 )  
        if @counter != (len(@string))
        begin
            set @returnString = @returnString + '_'
        end
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end
    return @returnString
END
GO
```

Then you can call the function in the select:

```
select dbo.Split_String('jai')
```

Result of this would be

> j_a_i

So you can do the update now, like this:

```
update photos set filename = dbo.Split_String(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

However, if you are looking for add `_` after each char then you could do that by  loop through (MS SQL Server) :

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(MAX)= 'jai';
DECLARE @POINTER INT= LEN(@DATA);
WHILE @POINTER > 1
    BEGIN
        SET @DATA = STUFF(@DATA, @POINTER, 0, '_');
        SET @POINTER = @POINTER - 1;
    END;
SELECT @DATA [DATA];
```

Result :

```
DATA
j_a_i
```